# Location detection

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using geometa.js on http://www.strahlen.org/map/central.htm to detect the browser's location. Works perfect and smooth in Chrome and Firefox,
but it doesn't always work for users with IE and/or Safari.

Is this something I can solve? 
Is there perhaps a better location script around that I could use, that works on all browsers/platforms?

Cheers, Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looks like](http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-examples/source/browse/trunk/whereareyou/scripts/geometa.js?r=187#2) geometa.js acts as a fallback for `navigator.geolocation` to get the location. That's great, it's the best way to do it, the only problem is that support isn't universal: 
http://caniuse.com/#search=geolocation

Comment: Thanks Josh! Good to read I did it the right way. And thanks for the interesting comptability link. Cheers! Frank