# Find My Location On Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, location

i am trying to make the application display my location on google maps with a geapoint, but it always opens the same place when opening the application on my phone, which is the value i added in the code as an initial value for the testing on the compiler.
how can i make it display my location(make it change the Latitude and longitude according to my place)?

here is the code:

public class AndroidGoogleMapsActivity extends MapActivity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Displaying Zooming controls
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    /**
     * Changing Map Type
     * */
     mapView.setSatellite(true); // Satellite View
    // mapView.setStreetView(true); // Street View
     mapView.setTraffic(true); // Traffic view

    /**
     * showing location by Latitude and Longitude
     * */        
    MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    double lat = Double.parseDouble("31.894178");
    double lon = Double.parseDouble("35.872694");
    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lon * 1E6));
    mc.animateTo(geoPoint);
    mc.setZoom(15);
    mapView.invalidate(); 



    /**
     * Placing Marker
     * */
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);
    AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = 
         new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);


    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Hello", "Sample Overlay item");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're never calling the actual GPS which is why it's reverting to the ones you programmed in. This is pretty well documented in other places, but here's a good place to start: http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/04/find-current-location-in-android-gps.html

Answer (score 0):

See [Location detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109644/location-detection) ; that's the easy way to do it afaik, and it worked for me. Cheers!